# Google map api v3 navigationControl css

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is this possible to change the location of navigationControl of Google map API v3 by using CSS?

I couldn't find any useful from google search.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to set the locations of the default controls (such as the navigationControl) is using javascript and the `ControlPosition` which you can read about [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#ControlPositioning).

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible, or at least very difficult, because the navigation controls dont have an id or a class name.

But you can "push" the control by inserting an "invisible" div like this:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var pushDiv = document.createElement('div');
pushDiv.style.height = '250px';
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(pushDiv);
```

Here I push the navigation control closer to the top.

Answer (score 0):

This example should help http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/textualzoom.html